# Better way to map categorical columns in pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe. These are some data from Shakib Al Hasna's ODI statistics.

```
    Run   Wicket    Run_Conceded    Catch       Opposition  Ground  Date        
0   30.0    1.0       39.0              0.0      Zimbabwe   Harare  6 Aug 2006  
1   20.0    2.0       32.0              0.0      Kenya      Nairobi (Gym)   12 Aug 2006 
2   13.0    1.0       26.0              0.0      Kenya      Nairobi (Gym)   13 Aug 2006 
3   25.0    0.0       28.0              0.0      Kenya      Nairobi (Gym)   15 Aug 2006 
4   67.0    0.0       23.0              0.0      Sri Lanka  Mohali  7 Oct 2006
```

So here I wanted to map the `Opposition` column in 4 category. Best, Good, Average, Satisfactory. Here's what I tried.

```
Best = ['England','India','New Zealand','South Africa']
Good = ['Australia','Pakistan','Sri Lanka','West Indies']
Average = ['Afghanistan','Zimbabwe','Netherlands','Ireland']
Satisfactory = ['Kenya', 'Bermuda','Canada','Scotland']

for B in Best:
    for i in range(len(df['Opposition'])):
        if df['Opposition'].iloc[i]== B:
            df['Opposition'].iloc[i] = "Best"
for G in Good:
    for i in range(len(df['Opposition'])):
        if df['Opposition'].iloc[i]== G:
            df['Opposition'].iloc[i] = "Good"
for A in Average:
    for i in range(len(df['Opposition'])):
        if df['Opposition'].iloc[i]== A:
            df['Opposition'].iloc[i] = "Average"
for S in Satisfactory:
    for i in range(len(df['Opposition'])):
        if df['Opposition'].iloc[i]== S:
            df['Opposition'].iloc[i] = "Satisfactory"
```

It's working fine. But I want to know is there any other easier way to do it?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Please note the existence of [CodeReview.se] which exists for the purpose of reviewing code that works. Make sure you read https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask and https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users before asking.

Comment: I'm new in this kind of problem. I don't have enough idea about searching with the right keyword. Hence I asked the question.

Comment: My point was that if the _code works but you want to improve it_, it can often go on [CodeReview.se]; Stack Overflow usually helps people with code that doesn't work.

Comment: Okay. I get it. So should I delete this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use apply and reduce over equal equal

```
def f(x):
    // condition here probably use reduce function to select

df["Opposition"].apply(f)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about :

```
df['Opposition'] = df.apply(lambda x: "Good" if x.Opposition in Good else x, axis=1)
```

and so forth?

Comment: Why not use a single function to decide the group. In this way code is clean and there is very less repetition.